# Python scatter - change marker style based on entity

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib

I'm struggling for days trying to resolve this problem: I have cartesian coordinates on the y-axis (for depth from 0 to 1) and numbers with different values on the x axis (the numbers are the firing rate of different cells populations at the given depth on y axis, so they vary randomly).
I would like to show bigger size of markers in the scatterplot corresponding to a bigger x-axis value (firing rate).
Thank you for any suggestion.
This is the code (not working).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

x = np.genfromtxt('x_dex.csv', delimiter=',')

y = np.genfromtxt('z_dex.csv', delimiter=',')

array = [i for i in x if i > 4]
array.sort()

s = [30*2**n for n in range(len(array))];

plt.subplot(212)

plt.scatter(x,y,s=s)

plt.show()
```

This is unfortunately not showing the correct relation between size of marker and depth.

Comment: First, can you explain what exactly is the correct relation between size of marker and depth, or rather, in what way this is currently not working? Can also you change the lines `x = np.genfromtxt('x_dex.csv', delimiter=',')` to generate either some appropriate random data or just write out a few entries? Edit it so we can copy, paste and run the code as you've written in the question and generate a plot with the issue. You'll get the most useful answers this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line where you compute your 'size' values looks incorrect to me:

```
s = [30*2**n for n in range(len(array))];
```

This will give you a list containing:

```
s = [30*2**0, 30*2**1, 30*2**2, ..., 30*2**(len(array) - 1)]
```

The values bear no relation to `y`, so I assume this is not what you intended. Maybe you meant something more like this:

```
s = 30 * 2 ** y
```

---

There are actually several other issues here:

- Don't give your variables names like `array` - this can lead to confusion with `numpy.array`. It's even worse in this case, since `array` is actually not an array but a Python `list`!
- Since you're dealing with numpy arrays, it's much faster to use vectorization rather than list comprehensions. For example, you could use:

  ```
  array = x[x > 4]
  ```

  rather than

  ```
  array = [i for i in x if i > 4]
  ```
- After your list comprehension `array = [i for i in x if i > 4]`, `array` will have a different number of elements to `y` if there are elements in `array` that are less than 4.
- `array.sort()` will sort the list *in place*, which means that the order of the elements in `array` will no longer match the order of elements in `y`.
- In fact, sorting seems rather pointless in this situation - since you're making a scatter plot the order of the points should not matter.
- You're not writing MATLAB code any more, so there's no need to end lines on a semicolon (although it won't do any harm if you do).

---

Here's my educated guess at what you're trying to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.genfromtxt('x_dex.csv', delimiter=',')
y = np.genfromtxt('z_dex.csv', delimiter=',')

# get the set of indices that will sort x in ascending order, apply these
# to both x & y
order = np.argsort(x)
x_sorted = x[order]
y_sorted = y[order]

# keep only xy pairs where x > 4
valid = x_sorted > 4
x_valid = x_sorted[valid]
y_valid = y_sorted[valid]

# compute the sizes
s = 30 * 2 ** y_valid

# plot
plt.subplot(212)
plt.scatter(x_valid, y_valid, s=s)

plt.show()
```